# Informix: Query merge

Tags: sql, informix

i have 2 queries:

```
select COUNT(o.id_offer) from offers o, product p where
 p.id_product = "+ productID +" and o.id_offer = "+ offerID +" and (b.type = 0 or o.type = "A")
```

this query returns the count of some product

```
select p.id_product, p.name, s.id_supplier, s.name from product p, suppliers s where p.id_supplier = s.id_supplier
```

this query returns all products data

i want to combine the two queries  in one, something like this:

```
select (select COUNT(o.id_offer) from offers o, product p where
 p.id_product = p.id_product and o.id_offer = 13345 and (b.type = 0 or o.type = "A")) count,p.id_product, p.name, s.id_supplier, s.name from product p, suppliers s where p.id_supplier = s.id_supplier
```

Anyone knows how to do this in informix?

Comment: Why did you tag this `mysql` if it's about Informix?

Comment: It's a common mistake for some reason. Can you explain why you did it?

Comment: You should finish disentangling your SQL from the string it was prepared in.  You also need to read up on [SQL Injection](http://xkcd.com/327).  It isn't clear what `b.type` refers to in the first query.  It would be helpful to have the schema for the tables — or at least an outline schema with the salient columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the explicit join notation, not the comma-list of table names in the FROM clause notation.

The first query needs generalizing to generate a product ID and the matching count.

```
SELECT p.id_product, COUNT(o.id_offer) AS offer_count
  FROM offers o
  JOIN product p ON p.id_product = o.id_product -- Guessed column
 WHERE (p.type = 0 OR o.type = 'A')
 GROUP BY p.id_product
```

The second query can be converted to:

```
SELECT p.id_product, p.name, s.id_supplier, s.name
  FROM product p
  JOIN suppliers s ON p.id_supplier = s.id_supplier
```

These two queries can be combined with a join, too:

```
SELECT x.id_product, x.product_name, x.id_supplier, x.supplier_name, y.offer_count
  FROM (SELECT p.id_product, p.name, s.id_supplier, s.name
          FROM product p
          JOIN suppliers s ON p.id_supplier = s.id_supplier
       ) AS x
  JOIN (SELECT p.id_product, COUNT(o.id_offer) AS offer_count
          FROM offers o
          JOIN product p ON p.id_product = o.id_product -- Guessed column
         WHERE (p.type = 0 OR o.type = 'A')
         GROUP BY p.id_product
       ) AS y
    ON x.id_product = y.id_product
```